# What does x[1] mean? Pseudocode, doesn't specify language (although I ss

Tags: computer-science, pseudocode

The following pseudocode calculates and outputs two values k and j. It then calculates and outputs to further values t and a.

```
x = [7, 9, 6, 2, 4]
t = x[1]
k = x[1]
j = x[1]
FOR n = 2 TO 5
    t = t + x[n]
    IF x[n] > k THEN
        k = x[n]
    ENDIF
    IF x[n] <j THEN
        j = x[n]
NEXT n
OUTPUT (“k = ”, k, (“j = ”,j)
t = t – k – j
a = t/3
a = int(a)
OUTPUT (“a = ”,a)
```

what does x[1] mean? at first I thought it meant that the variable (eg: t) was = to the 1st argument of the array x.
But then I realised that then t, k, and j would all have the same values...

Comment: You're right , its the first element of the array. t,k and stay start off with same initial values but then inside the loop they are reassigned!

Comment: It should be the first index of the x array, which is 7. What is wrong with all t,k and j initializing with the same value (7)? Later in the for loop and if statements the values are changed.

Comment: One caveat: in this case (using `x[n]` for n=2..5) I assume index 1 is the *first* item in the array (value 7), but many languages start their array indices at 0 (and index 1 would then be value 9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[1]` is the index of the `x` array.  In this case, `x[1]` has a value of `9`.

Answer (score 0):

**[ ]**  is array demonstation. x[n] means n th element of the array "x".